# general system exception happened additional data: class name and class type already exists

Tags: magento-2.1, csv, import-products

while importing in magento 2 getting this error

> general system exception happened additional data: class name and class type already exists.

when i check in var/import_history/filename_error.csv

```
sku,store_view_code,attribute_set_code,brand,product_type,categories,
product_websites,name,description,short_description,weight, 
product_online,tax_class_name,visibility,price,finish,color,capacity,
width,depth,height,length,thickness,crank,opening_angle,size,sets_pcs,
special_price,special_price_from_date,special_price_to_date,url_key,
meta_title,meta_keywords,meta_description,base_image,base_image_label,
small_image,small_image_label,thumbnail_image,thumbnail_image_label,
swatch_image,swatch_image_label,created_at,updated_at,new_from_date,
new_to_date,display_product_options_in,cost,msp,msrp_price,
map_enabled,gift_message_available,custom_design,custom_design_from,
custom_design_to,custom_layout_update,page_layout,
product_options_container,msrp_display_actual_price_type,
country_of_manufacture,qty,additional_attributes,out_of_stock_qty,
use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,allow_backorders,
use_config_backorders,min_cart_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,
max_cart_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,
notify_on_stock_below,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,
use_config_manage_stock,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,
use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,
website_id,related_skus,related_position,crosssell_skus,
crosssell_position,upsell_skus,upsell_position,additional_images,
additional_image_labels,hide_from_product_page,bundle_price_type,
bundle_sku_type,bundle_price_view,bundle_weight_type,bundle_values,
bundle_shipment_type,associated_skus,grade,warrantyinfo,
unit_of_measurement,typeofproductfitting,type,shape,certifications,
audience,guaranteeinfo,model,hsn_sac,pack_quantity,offers,mpn,
isaccessoryorsparepartfor,isconsumablefor,releasedate,
initialproductiondate,pattern,productsupport,isbasedon,owns,
itemcondition,product_property,vendor_group,plt,errors
```

At the end of csv header only errors added any no other informations.

Comment: When u getting this error ?

Comment: I got the issue ... Its was wrong spelling in tax_class_name value...

Comment: ok so now ur issue resolve ?