# Magento 2 - New product import error - Class name and class type already exists error during import

Tags: error, magento2.3.4, product-import

If try to import new product i am getting following error,

[image]

How to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Either pass the unique urls or do not pass. If you do not pass then Magento will auto generate the URLs

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue occurred due to typo mistake in the field name.

Please refer to the [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/210073)

Comment: I did so many times cross  checked, no spelling error.

Comment: Anything else i forget to do?

Comment: Export the data csv, compare the fields and it's data type. Please try to import for single row, if it is working then add chunk of rows and import. So you can clarify whether the issue in any specific row or in the whole csv file format.